# Working with Blend 2015 and Windows Universal Apps

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, blend

I was working successfully on Windows Phone 8.1 projects in Blend for Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 as well.
I'm using Blend just for getting default style definitions and adjusting them.

In the Windows Phone 8.1 project, there is a Objects and Timeline windows, where I can see the elements hierarchy and do Edit Style -> Edit a Copy...

In the Windows Universal Apps I have a Document Outline windows instead which offers no possibility for work with styles.

How can I work with styles in WUA?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Objects and Timeline window is available for Universal apps. If it's turned off you can get it back from the View.Other Windows menu or with Ctrl+Alt+T. Edit Style is also available on the Format menu.

[image]

Comment: Ok, Ctrl+Alt+T opens Document Outline menu and I don't have any Format menu. I have Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio Community 2015 version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1. See here pls: http://oi67.tinypic.com/k0mxhi.jpg